# Change the "Run as" property in a Data Collector Set with Powershell

Tags: sql, powershell, performance, odbc, perfmon

So I made a script that loops through servers and sets up DataSources and Data Collector Sets.
The script works, but there is one issue, and I've lost hope.

The DataCollector Set runs per default as "SYSTEM", but that makes it impossible to start the Datacollector Set, because I need it to be a "USER" that has access to the SQL Server where the Performance Monitor is saving the collected data.

This is an example of what the idea is.:
[image: This is a Example what the Idea is.]

Im setting up a ODBC DataSource and a DataCollector Set on Server 1, Server 2....
They save the Perfmon Data to a SQL Database in another, Monitoring Dedicated SQL Server.

I can change the "Run as" property in the Data Collector Set manually, but that is no one's goal.
I need to be able to change it with Powershell.

I need to change this property, but with Powershell. And everything will work.
[image: I need to change this Property but with Powershell. And everything will work.]

Comment: If you use the COM `Pla.DataCollectorSet` objects like the example here, you can set `$dataCollectorSet.UserAccount` https://pscdoc.com/node/51. Be aware of the difference between the data collector user and the task scheduler user if you're using tasks too. See some of the other properties in the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-pla/1809d280-56e0-4c78-9546-ad1869c3a16a

Comment: I just tried it. It seems that the value is readonly.
I cannot set it...

Comment: You are correct, it looks like there's a separate method to set the values instead: `$dataCollectorSet.SetCredentials('Username','password')`